# RuntimeError is coming in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error when i am submitting the form using Rails 3.

Error:

RuntimeError in HcsysController#create

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
Rails.root: C:/Site/swargadwar_admin

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/hcsys_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Please check my below codes and try to help me to resolve this error.

## views/hcsys/new_html.erb

```
<center>
    <%= form_for :hcsy,:url => {:action => "create",:id => params[:id] } do |f| %>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Deceased Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :dece_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Beneficiary name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for "name"> Address line -1</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_address1 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for "name"> Address line -2</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_address2 %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name"> Village</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_village %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Block</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_block %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Dist</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_dist %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">State</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_state %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">country</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_country %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Police station</label>
        <%= f.text_field :beneficiary_ps %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Occupation</label>
        <%= f.text_field :occupation %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">BPL</label>
        Yes: <%= f.radio_button :bpl,'Yes',:checked => true %>
        No : <%= f.radio_button :bpl,'No' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Date of Required</label>
        <%= f.text_field :date_of_required,:id => "popupDatepicker" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Recieved fund earlier</label>
         Yes:<%= f.radio_button :recieved_fund_earlier,'Yes',:checked => true %>
         No: <%= f.radio_button :recieved_fund_earlier,'No' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Mobile no</label>
        <%= f.telephone_field :mobile %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Previous reciept no</label>
        <%= f.text_field :prev_receipt_no %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Previous amount recieved</label>
        <%= f.text_field :prev_amount_recieved %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Goverment service</label>
        <%= f.text_field :govt_service %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Business</label>
        <%= f.text_field :business %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Land property</label>
        <%= f.text_field :land_property %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Others</label>
        <%= f.text_field :others %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name"> Amount Required</label>
        <%= f.text_field :amount_required %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Photo</label>
        <%= f.file_field :bphoto %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Doner photo</label>
        <%= f.file_field :dphoto %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for= "name">Created</label>
        <%= f.number_field :created_by %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Updated</label>
        <%= f.number_field :updated_by %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for ="name">Brahmin</label>
         Yes:<%= f.radio_button :brahmin,'Yes',:checked => true %>
         No: <%= f.radio_button :brahmin,'No' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
</center>
```

## controller/hcsys_controller.rb

```
class HcsysController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @hcsy=Hcsy.new
    end
    def show
        @hcsy=Hcsy.all
    end
    def create
        @sdf=Sdf.find(params[:id])
        @hcsy=Hcsy.new(params[:hcsy])
        @hcsy.sdp_id=@sdp.id
        if @hcsy.save
        flash[:notice]="data has successfully saved"
        flash[:color]="valid"
        redirect_to :action => "new" ,:controller => "admins"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

## migrate/20150408170838_create_hcsies.rb

```
class CreateHcsies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hcsies do |t|
      t.integer :sdp_id
      t.integer :receipt_no
      t.string :dece_name
      t.string :beneficiary_name
      t.integer :beneficiary_relationship_id
      t.string :beneficiary_relationship_other
      t.string :beneficiary_address1
      t.string :beneficiary_address2
      t.string :beneficiary_village
      t.string :beneficiary_block
      t.string :beneficiary_dist
      t.string :beneficiary_state
      t.string :beneficiary_country
      t.string :beneficiary_ps
      t.string :mobile
      t.string :occupation
      t.boolean :bpl
      t.string :govt_service
      t.string :business
      t.string :land_property
      t.string :others
      t.boolean :brahmin
      t.decimal :amount_required, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.date :date_of_required
      t.boolean :recieved_fund_earlier
      t.string :prev_receipt_no
      t.decimal :prev_amount_recieved, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.string :dphoto
      t.string :bphoto
      t.string :b_audio
      t.string :b_thumb
      t.integer :created_by
      t.integer :updated_by

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## model/hcsy.rb

```
class Hcsy < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount_required, :b_audio, :b_thumb, :beneficiary_address1, :beneficiary_address2, :beneficiary_block, :beneficiary_country, :beneficiary_dist, :beneficiary_name, :beneficiary_ps, :beneficiary_relationship_id, :beneficiary_relationship_other, :beneficiary_state, :beneficiary_village, :bphoto, :bpl, :brahmin, :business, :created_by, :date_of_required, :dece_name, :dphoto, :govt_service, :land_property, :mobile, :occupation, :others, :prev_amount_recieved, :prev_receipt_no, :receipt_no, :recieved_fund_earlier, :sdp_id, :updated_by
  mount_uploader :bphoto, BphotoUploader
  mount_uploader :dphoto, DphotoUploader
  belongs_to :sdf
end
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `@hcsy.sdp_id=@sdp.id` to `@hcsy.sdp_id=@sdf.id` ... just `@sdf.id`